# Объединить две выборки из таблицы М:М с учётом count

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Есть три таблицы: арты, теги и связующая таблица для проставления тегов для каждого арта.

**main_tags** — все теги;

**arts** — арты;

**tag_to_art** — связь тегов и артов;

Часть данных из таблиц:

```
SELECT id, ru FROM main_tags ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5;

 id |       ru
----+-----------------
  2 | мужчина
  3 | девушка
  4 | длинные волосы
  5 | короткие волосы
  6 | на улице
```

```
SELECT id FROM arts;

 id
----
  4
  5
```

```
SELECT * FROM tag_to_art;

         tag          | art
----------------------+-----
 девушка              |   5
 девушка              |   4
 длинные волосы       |   5
 на улице             |   4
```

Выходит, что на арте с id **4** два тега: девушка и на улице, а на арте **5** - девушка и длинные волосы.

Вот так можно найти все теги, которые проставлены на отдельный арт по его id:

```
SELECT main_tags.id, tag_to_art.tag
FROM main_tags
JOIN tag_to_art ON main_tags.ru = tag_to_art.tag
WHERE tag_to_art.art = '4';

 id |         tag
----+----------------------
  6 | на улице
  3 | девушка
```

Таким образом можно найти сколько раз был привязан тег к разным артам:

```
SELECT COUNT(tag) FROM tag_to_art
WHERE tag = 'девушка';

 count
-------
     2
```

**Вопрос:** *Как мне объединить оба запроса, чтобы получить на выходе такой вид:*

```
 id |         tag          | count
----+----------------------+-------
  4 | длинные волосы       |     1
  3 | девушка              |     2
```

**Моя попытка:**

```py
    art_id = 4 # сюда приходит любой id по запросу

    cur.execute(f"""SELECT main_tags.id, tag_to_art.tag, COUNT(tag_to_art.tag) AS count
                FROM main_tags
                JOIN tag_to_art ON main_tags.ru = tag_to_art.tag
                WHERE tag_to_art.art = '{art_id}'
                GROUP BY main_tags.id, tag_to_art.tag
                ORDER BY count, date DESC
                """)

    data = cur.fetchall()
```

Увы, но таким образом почти всё верно, но подсчитывает только количество использования тега на конкретном арте, а не во всей таблице.

```
 id |         tag          | count
----+----------------------+-------
  4 | длинные волосы       |     1
  3 | девушка              |     1 # но здесь должно быть 2, оно подсчитало только на одном арте
```

Мне необходимо или используя один запрос (можно с подзапросами), или инструментами Python сделать на выходе необходимый вид.

Comment: Хранение tag вместо его id в связующей таблице - так себе идея... равно как и передача критерия отбора для числового поля в виде строкового литерала. Ну и бардак с именами полей...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.tag, COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM main_tags t1
JOIN tag_to_art t2 ON t1.ru = t2.tag
JOIN arts t3 ON t2.art = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.tag
HAVING MAX((t2.art = 4)::INT) = 1;
```

| id | tag | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | на улице | 1 |
| 3 | девушка | 2 |

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.tag, COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM main_tags t1
JOIN tag_to_art t2 ON t1.ru = t2.tag
JOIN arts t3 ON t2.art = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.tag
HAVING MAX((t2.art = 5)::INT) = 1;
```

| id | tag | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | девушка | 2 |
| 4 | длинные волосы | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CdF9EwbX)

Comment: Судя по всему, в postgresql немного иначе работает, ибо: ОШИБКА:  функция sum(boolean) не существует
LINE 6: HAVING SUM(t2.art = 5);
               ^
HINT:  Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.

Comment: @mrBars1k Просмотрел фамилию СУБД, сорри. Поправил.